How far has a national team gone in an international tournament without conceding a goal in open play?
France has made it to the semi-finals of Euro 2024 without being scored on in open play all tournament! They've had 4 clean sheets on route to their match again Spain. The only goal they conceded was a penalty against Poland.
Similar to How far has a national team gone in an international tournament without scoring a goal in the open play? What's the furthest a national team has made it in an international tournament (World cup, continental cups) without conceding a goal in open play?
Competitions have had fewer rounds and different formats throughout the years. So please include the number of matches played and minimum number of matches a team was guaranteed given the format (ex, in Euro 2024 each team was guaranteed 3 games).

They have conceded a goal, actually: a Robert Lewandowski penalty in a 1-1 draw with Poland in the group stage. They haven't conceded a goal from open play, though.

You're completely correct, updated to specify that I only meant open play

Not sure if this is a complete list, I could've missed some teams that conceded multiple penalties:
Colombia won the 2001 Copa America without conceding a goal.
Cameroon won the 2002 African Cup of Nations.
Ivory Coast reached the final of the 2012 African Cup of Nations and lost on penalties without conceding a single goal.
New Zealand won the OFC Nations Cup in 2024 without conceding a goal. So did Australia in 2000 and 1996.
New Zealand also won in 2016 without conceding a goal in open play.

Surprised that some winners never had a goal against (other that in Oceania). But also reading the linked pages, didn't know that Argentina pulled out of 2001 Copa America due to security threats.
